# Flutter Screen Navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

[image]

Assuming that i am on Location Page,Now User Navigates to Location Page 1 and 2 to add new location and then Navigates to Last Page which effectively return Location Page with updated address

```
**Stack Trace**

**Before Adding Location**                           

Locaction Page                              
        |
        |
  Main Page


**After Adding Location** 

    Location Page
          |
          | 
    Last Page
          |
          |
  Set Location page 2
          |
          |
  Set Location Page 1
          |
          |
  Locaction Page                              
          |
          |
    Main Page
```

Now what problem this is causing is after the new location is added the user is able to navigate back again to the Set Location Page 2-->Set Location Page1---->Old Location Page which is not desired.

What I need to do is the behaviour same as before adding the address but with Location page updated with new location

How can i achieve this using Navigator Widget,so that once the new location has been added by user, i could effictively pop out Set Location Page 1,2 and Old Location Page
with restriction that popping could only be done once we are at Set Location Page2/Last Page

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with awaiting the the nextpage to pop

psuedo code

```
mainPage{
 goToNextPage()async{
  await Navigator.of(ctxt).pushNamed('/page-with-location-update');

  // "/page-with-location-update" screen popped
  // here you can call to check whether the location is updated
  if(locationIsUpdated){
   setState();
  }
 }
}
```